# Sql database recover and saving history copy yearly

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a database of 25 tables read and write by C# code, some of tables should closed yearly and clear to refill in the new year, but a history copy should save for any later check or report.

So, what is the best way to do this?!!! knowing that, in the database there are tables (like: Employees table) which should be keep as last version without any change, while an another table (like: sale table) should be cleared form data.

Comment: why should they be closed yearly? Do you ever need to run reports or access past data? what about foreign keys in other tables? How many records do you have? Why not just filter by year? A properly indexed table will have fast selects. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: Each table have a huge records, and each table have audit table for it, so my data will became huge at the end of each year. in addition, some of table its columns is the year months, so I can't use it only ones.

Comment: just out of curosity, what is huge? hundreds of thousands, millions, hundreds of millions, or more? If you want to do this, you just have to write a routine that copies data from one table to another (see the syntax for INSERT INTO...SELECT), delete the records in tables that you want to, being wary of foreign keys and such. Test thoroughly on a backup before running on your prod system.

Comment: Yes, It is really huge, but the data size is not the real cause. the real cause is the table design (table column is the year months), and I should do the Restore. I am searching for the best way for doing this restore, best performance, fastest one. the procedure i have it now is as follow: getting a backup copy, rename current one, restore a new copy, drop tables which need to be clean, recreate the dropped tables without data (Schema only).

Comment: why not just TRUNCATE the tables that need to be cleared? That will reset any identity fields, and it is MUCH faster than a DELETE statement, because a TRUNCATE is not fully logged.

Comment: also check over in http://dba.stackexchange.com/ . They are much more knowledgable about general DB questions like this.

Comment: thank you Mr. Jeremy TRUNCATE is very a good idea. Now, the problem is in Rename the OldOne to reuse its name for the NewOne. the problem is, the rename query doesn't rename the (LDF and MDF) file, so i can't reuse the name! is there a way to do this?! without giving full path of this files ?!!!

Comment: see http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/122/retore-sql-server-database-to-different-filenames-and-locations/

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jeremy to help me. the link you send me was helpful. i hope to move the conversation from comment to answer to be helpful for other